# What php framework should I learn?

Tags: php

I have been making web applications for a couple years with the standard php/html/javascript/css. I have recently started using jquery with javascript and that made me realize how great frameworks can be.

I am looking into learning a php framework and am not sure where to start. So far I have read about Zend Framework and Symfony and they both sound good but also look hard to learn. Which framework is best for beginners that will also aid in learning proper MVC structure.

Comment: @Doug T this should have been an answer, great analogy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What PHP framework would you choose for a new application and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why)

Comment: If you want to learn about MVC, then you should stay away from php frameworks. Most of them are just Rails clones, implementing same mistakes and , of course, add on top of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get very far on other people's personal preferences (the answers you'll find here).

Instead dive into a couple and choose one you like. Think about it like shopping for a car. Shop around, test drive, find one you enjoy and is reasonably well supported.

Answer (score 1):

Code Igniter is pretty great: http://codeigniter.com/ It's simple, easy to learn, and has company backing by EllisLabs (makers of ExpressionEngine CMS).

I also like Symfony. It's not too difficult, but I wouldn't recommend it if you're uncomfortable with Object Oriented Programming (which Symfony 2 uses heavily).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Symfony, because:

- Uses I think the best ORM (Doctrine: database abstraction layer)
- Very well structured framework (from classes to folders)
- Very very optimized code (so the web apps load quickly)
- A lot of plugins (even you can use plugins from other frameworks like Zend)
- Great tutorials
- Big/Great community

Like Jordan says you should have a very good fundamentals in OOP. Maybe you should take a look at their website http://symfony.com/get_started. I Suggest you to learn Symfony2 (this is the new version at this moment)

Answer (score 1):

I recommended Yii framework. because:

-Model-View-Controller (MVC) design pattern

- Database Access Objects (DAO), Query Builder, Active Record, DB Migration
- Form input and validation
- AJAX-enabled widgets
- Authentication and authorization
- Skinning and theming
- Web services
- Internationalization (I18N) and localization (L10N)
- Layered caching scheme
- Error handling and logging
- Security
- Unit and functionality testing
- Automatic code generation
- Compliance to XHTML
- Purely object-oriented
- Friendly with third-party code
- Detailed documentation
- Extension library

and if you want more reason to choose yii.Then check this link

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/performance/
```

and a very useful link

```
http://www.phpframeworks.com/
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: That link it is not a good reference because it's their website.

Comment: ya but you can check the performance of Yii as compared to other framworks...

Comment: yes, I can see that... but the question is "who's comparing them?", of course Yii.

Comment: yaa but if you check this link you can see how Yii is a good framework     http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: I know Yii is a good framework, I have no doubts about that. Very good comparison table, just a little bit outdated.